# Wordpress SEO by Yoast doesn't display meta tags on paginated pages

Tags: wordpress, seo, keyword

I have a wordpress site that has SEO Meta tags populated by Yoast plugin.

This seems to work fine, except on any paginated page.  On page2 or higher there is no

`<meta name="description" >` tag.  Is there a simple setting I need to change?  I can't find anything about it online at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if your Wordpress `header.php` has a line with:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

That allows Wordpress to inject code in the header. It has to be just before the closing head tag `</head>`. If not present just add it.